# Upload Image File and store MYSQL Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload an image to my site through a form and I'm having trouble with my form and really don't know where to go:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('login/save');?>   
    
        <table>
           
            <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title"></input></td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /> </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input></td>
            </tr>       
        </table>
    <?php
        echo form_close();
    ?>
```

**My controller:**

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->model('mlogin');
        $this->load->view('login/a', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }
    public function save(){
    
            $this->load->model("Mlogin");        
            if($this->input->post("submit")){
            
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '1000';
            if ( function_exists( 'date_default_timezone_set' ) ) date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh');
            $date = date("His_dmY_");
            $config['file_name']  = $date;
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('login/a', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                
            }       
                }
            //redirect("login/a");
            
                
            $this->Mlogin->add();   
                echo "Success!";
                }
            
    
}        
?>
```

**My Model:**

```
<?php
class Mlogin extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        
        
    }
    
    public function add(){
        $title = $this->input->post("title");
        $data = array(
            "title"=>$title,
            "image"=>$file_name
            );
        $this->db->insert("abc",$data);    
            }//end of simpan        
 }      
?>
```

Should I be doing something different? Not really sure what's going wrong.?
**Error:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: file_name
>
> Filename: models/mlogin.php
>
> Line Number: 23
>
> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Champ 'title' inconnu dans field list
>
> INSERT INTO `abc` (`title`, `image`) VALUES ('342342', NULL)
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Comment: Your model's `$file_name` not define. You should send a parameter as $file_name to your model's `add`

Comment: How would I fix? Can you help me?

Comment: Your controller call model's `add` method should pass parameter => `$this->Mlogin->add(YOUR_FILE_NAME_VARIABLE);`. And you model's method should modify like this `public function add($file_name)`